# How to apply the last part of the code for all sheets

Tags: vba

I need to apply the last part of my code to all the sheets and my code is supposed to combine duplicate dates and sum up its subtotal.

I only have tried pressing F5 to each of the sheets.

```
Sub CaseStudy()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range
Dim nRng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng
    If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
        .Add Dn.Value, Dn.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        .Item(Dn.Value).Value = .Item(Dn.Value).Value + Dn.Offset(, 1)
            If nRng Is Nothing Then
                Set nRng = Dn
            Else
                Set nRng = Union(nRng, Dn)
            End If
    End If
Next
If Not nRng Is Nothing Then nRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

I wanted to automatically apply the code to all the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Divide and rule" is one of the best ways to build code. Thus, pass every worksheet to the `Sub CaseStudy` as a parameter.

In order to get every worksheet, loop through the `Worksheets` collection of the workbook:

```
Sub ApplyToAllSheets()

    Dim wks As Worksheet        
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        CaseStudy wks
    Next

End Sub

Sub CaseStudy(wks As Worksheet)
    Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range
    Dim nRng As Range
    With wks
        Set Rng = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
            .Add Dn.Value, Dn.Offset(, 1)
        Else
            .Item(Dn.Value).Value = .Item(Dn.Value).Value + Dn.Offset(, 1)
                If nRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set nRng = Dn
                Else
                    Set nRng = Union(nRng, Dn)
                End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not nRng Is Nothing Then nRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Zha - glad to know I helped 